# How can I set up Kontact to sync with Hotmail calendar?

Tags: sync, calendar, kontact

I have just ditched Windows and installed Ubuntu 15.04 on my machine as I can't stand the horrible performance of Windows (it takes about 20 minutes from boot to become responsive, and another 10 minutes after suspend). However, I don't know how to set up Hotmail calendar in Kontact. I can't even Google about Hotmail calendar client on Linux in general.

What should I install in order to get my Kontact filled with my Hotmail calendar, with full read-write access?